# Difficulty using LUDecomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm having trouble using `LUDecomposition` with pivoting. I read the *Mathematica* help on this particular command, but I'm still lost. Take a matrix like:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}}
```

I evaluated

```
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}}]
```

and got

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -5}}, {1, 3, 2}, 0}
> ```

I don't really understand how to interpret this result, assuming that it's correct.

Comment: You may also take a look at the last comment in [this link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/274235)

Answer (score 15):

```
m = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}};
{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[m];
l = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j < i -> 1, {3, 3}] + IdentityMatrix[3];
u = lu SparseArray[{i_, j_} /; j >= i -> 1, {3, 3}];
l.u == m[[p]]
(* True *)
```

> l.u is equal to a permutation of the rows of m

```
MatrixForm /@ {l, u}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It'd be more idiomatic to use `UpperTriangularize[]` and `LowerTriangularize[]`. ;)

Comment: @J.M. Not in my mindset, but feel free to edit or post another answer if you think there is something meaningful that I'm leaving aside

Comment: Alright, I might do so later…

Answer (score 12):

As noted in the docs for `LUDecomposition[]`, the two triangles are by default returned together as a single array; this is customary for LU decomposition routines, as in the original LINPACK and MATLAB's [`lu()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html). In fact, exactly this same format is stored internally by the `LinearSolveFunction[]` returned by `LinearSolve[]`:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}};
{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}}]
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -5}}, {1, 3, 2}, 1}

ls = LinearSolve[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}}];
ls[[2, 3]]
   {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -5}}, {1, 3, 2}, 1}
```

You will need the first two results to reconstitute your original matrix. (The third result is a valuable diagnostic quantity called the [*matrix condition number*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConditionNumber.html); I should hope that this will eventually be introduced to you in your classes.)

In MATLAB, one could use the utility functions [`tril()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tril.html) and [`triu()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) to extract the triangular factors from the compressed array representing the LU decomposition. In *Mathematica*, on the other hand, belisarius has shown the way it used to be done. However, since version 7, *Mathematica* has been able to catch up to MATLAB in this regard, since the functions `LowerTriangularize[]` and `UpperTriangularize[]` became built-in:

```
l = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[lu]]
   {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 1}}

u = UpperTriangularize[lu]
   {{1, 2, 3}, {0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, -5}}
```

To reconstitute the permutation matrix, do this:

```
p = IdentityMatrix[Length[lu]][[piv]]
   {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}}
```

Now, we can easily check the decomposition:

```
p.a - l.u
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}
```

As an aside, here is how one computes `Det[a]` using the results of `LUDecomposition[a]`:

```
{Signature[piv] Tr[lu, Times], Det[a]}
   {5, 5}
```

Comment: Ups, I understood that you meant to use `Upper/LowerTriangularize` _instead of_  `LUDecomposition`. Ha!

Answer (score 3):

## Alternative Implementation

Hidden deep in the documentation code is supplied for explicit LU-factorization.

```
Documentation`HelpLookup@"Compatibility/tutorial/LinearAlgebra/MatrixManipulation"
```

[image]

```
LUmatrices[mm_?MatrixQ] := Module[
                                  {m},
                                  m=First@LUDecomposition[mm];
                                  {m - # + IdentityMatrix[Length@m], #} &[m*Array[Boole[# <= #2] &, Dimensions@m]]
                          ];
```

---

```
A = {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 4, 1}, {2, 5, 7}};
MatrixForm /@ LUmatrices[a]
```

Here is the output for your matrix.

[image]

I do not know how efficient or general this implementation is.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why people are complicating this more than it should be.

You did the `LUDecomposition` function and got this:

```
 {{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -5}}, {1, 3, 2}, 1}
```

All you need to do is grab the first part of this answer, so the matrix:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 0, -5}}
```

To make it easier input it as an actual matrix form

---

From here it is *super* easy to see the answer once you know how to interpret it

For the **Lower triangular matrix** all you do is:

1. Keep the values in red in the lower part of the matrix
2. Erase the diagonal entries and everything above
3. Replace the diagonal entries by 1's
4. Everything else above by 0's
5. Voila your L matrix

Like so:

[image: As you can guess the Upper triangular]

---

As you can guess the **Upper triangular matrix** is similar to this:

1. You grab the same matrix with all the entries
2. This time you erase everything below the diagonal and replace it by 0's
3. Voila your U matrix

Like so:

[image]

That is literally all you need to do, it seems long when I explain but this is such a quick way to do this.

This works *everytime* with all matrices.

Comment: This is what both J.M. and belisarius did though. How would you write it in *Mathematica* code?

Comment: That is the whole point though. I am giving a new perspective on the same problem for some people who are just starting. It took me a while to get the hang of Mathematica codes and syntax which is unintuitive if you are learning alone. If you can simplify doing things on Mathematica it's very time saving. I only use the codes when I really have a restriction otherwise why would you? Someone just starting on Mathematica will have no clue what these codes are and most people explain poorly the sequence and relation of things. Look how beautifully this gives you the answer, why do you need code?

Comment: ok, I see where you are coming from now. There are many reasons why we assume people want to use the LU decomposition programmatically. Usually, the LU decomposition is just one step in a long chain of computations. Mathematica can be used to make all the computations for a given input. This makes it possible to experiment with lots of different inputs and get answers within milliseconds. With your approach, there would be copy and paste involved for getting each answer. Second, the values in the matrix may not be integers and you may lose precision if you read values off of the matrix form.

Comment: Third, the problems dealt with in Mathematica can be very large. Imagine trying to use your approach on a problem where the matrices as $10^4$ by $10^4$ elements. This is not unrealistic. So the reason is simply: people don't typically use Mathematica for simple problems where your approach is feasible. The problems are either much larger, require higher precision, or are not the one-off kind of problem.

Comment: I do remember also thinking that many answers poorly explain what they are doing when I was starting out with Mathematica. This becomes less and less of an issue the more you know about the Mathematica language. In this case, I find J.M.'s answer very readable, but then again I'm not a beginner anymore.

Comment: I know you are getting critical, and that is great, but don't worry I am just giving a way to do it for those starting out. If you encounter a problem with complex numbers then, as I said above in my first comment, don't take my method. The whole point of Stack Exchange is to provide lots of answers for various problems because not everyone can understand or solve things the same.

Comment: Remember that introductory linear classes are in fact very solvable with this method because they don't give any of the exceptions you mentioned, at least any linear I encountered never did at first. For later problems perfectly understandable to use complex codes.