# Different Value for LU Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

When I try to LU decompose a matrix m, I get a different result in mathematica than an online calculator. Mathematica also gives me values that is different from my own derived values for the elements of L and U matrices. Can anyone shed some light on what mathematica is doing?

```
m = {{2, -3, 1, 3}, {1, 4, -3, -3}, {5, 3, -1, -1}, {3, -6, -3, 1}}
{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[m]
```

The matrix lu needs to be decomposed to get L and U

```
l = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length[lu]]
u = UpperTriangularize[lu]
```

The determinant of m is -160. The product of the determinant of L and U should be equal to that but it isn't. From an online calculator, I get this.

[LU Decomposition Calculator](http://www.gregthatcher.com/Mathematics/LU_Factorization.aspx)

[image]

Comment: You have to also consider the determinant of the permutation matrix (from pivoting).  (The decomposition is $PM=LU$.)  The determinant of the permutation matrix corresponding to `piv` is `-1`.  Thus the product of the determinants of `l` and `u` should be `Det[m[[piv]]` or `160`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, one should use `Signature[]` to ensure the correct sign for the determinant.

```
m = {{2, -3, 1, 3}, {1, 4, -3, -3}, {5, 3, -1, -1}, {3, -6, -3, 1}}
{lu, piv, cond} = LUDecomposition[m]

{Signature[piv] Tr[lu, Times], Det[m]}
```

as noted in [this previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89679).

Answer (score 1):

```
m = {{2, -3, 1, 3}, {1, 4, -3, -3}, {5, 3, -1, -1}, {3, -6, -3, 1}};

{lu, p, c} = LUDecomposition[m];
u = UpperTriangularize@lu;
l = LowerTriangularize[lu, -1] + IdentityMatrix[Length@m];
```

the original matrix is obtained:

```
Permute[l.u, p]
{{2, -3, 1, 3}, {1, 4, -3, -3}, {5, 3, -1, -1}, {3, -6, -3, 1}}
m == %
True

Det@m
-160

Det[Permute[l.u, p]]
-160

Det[l.u]
160  (* is not correct*)
```

l.u is equal to a permutation of the rows of m:

```
l.u == m[[p]]
True
```

lookup in the docs